# What is the frequency distribution of a random variable representing the result of the launch of one dice?

Tags: probability-distributions

What is the frequency distribution of a random variable representing the result of the launch of one die?

I don't if that is correct but:

$S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

The probability of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is the same, $\frac{1}{6}$.

Can I say: $X$ ~ Uniform$(1,6)$?

Comment: I dunno, my kids seem to throw sixes an awful lot of the time...

Comment: fyi, "dice" is plural. If the die is unbiased then the distribution is uniform on {1,...,6}, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct..........